# python: generate paragraph based on input variables

Tags: python

Based on the following paragraph:

```
configure terminal
session-router
access-control
        realm-id                          ##REALM_ID##
        description                       "##DESCRIPTION##"
        source-address                    ##SOURCE_ADDR##
done
exit
exit
exit
```

I want to generate the following paragraph (this will be my actual networking component):

```
        module_args = {
                "REALM_ID": {"default": True, "type": "str"},
                "DESCRIPTION": {"default": True, "type": "str"},
                "SOURCE_ADDR": {"default": True, "type": "str"}
                }

        f.write('access-control'+ '\n'
'          realm-id               '+module.params["REALM_ID"]+ '\n'
'          description            '+module.params["DESCRIPTION"]+ '\n'
'          source-address         '+module.params["SOURCE_ADDR"]+ '\n'
'          done'+ '\n'
'          exit'+ '\n'
'exit'+ '\n'
'exit'+ '\n')
        f.close()
```

You can hopefully see the correlations. How would I best go about this task?

I understand that this may be a bit more complex, as I am actually trying to automate my automation. Thanks.

Comment: Change the paragraph into something that would allow to do this more easily (or explain where you get this paragraph from and why it can't be adapted to serve this purpose).

Comment: You can change the original code snippet, but it kind of loses its value then... unless the change is quick and easy to implement. As I said, I am trying to automate my automation, so it will be more tricky logically.

Comment: Hang on a second! You say "here is the input (1), how can I generate the output (2)?". But looking closely, It seems that the so-called output is in fact a piece of code which generates the input. So what exactly are you asking here?????

Comment: I can see what you mean, but this isn't the case. How does output (2) generate output (1)? If you copied output (2) into a .py file and run it, would it generate output (1)? Of course not. The "module.params" prefix in output (2) actually signifies a variable to be used later in the output (2) file; the output (2) you see in the thread is actually a snippet of a larger file, whereas output (1) is the complete file. Hopefully that clarifies things.